# How to add Line Break on ViewText?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I'm a newbie. I'm editing Searchable Dictionary given to sample on SDK.
Dictionary follows a database on \res\raw\definitions.txt

when searching word shows result (defination) like below-

```
line1 line2 line3
```

But I want to add line break on result and show (defination) like below-

```
line1 
line2 
line3
```

code of WordActivity.java is here

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word);

        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            finish();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
            TextView definition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);


            int wIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD);
            int dIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION);

            word.setText(cursor.getString(wIndex));
            definition.setText(cursor.getString(dIndex));
        }}   
            public void onBackPressed() {
                onSearchRequested();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            case R.id.about:
                setContentView(R.layout.abouttanzil);
                return true;
            case R.id.exit:
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what should i add and where to make line break??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: line1 is for one TextView, line2 for second and so on?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its like a line contains: Drug name: Cepro, Price: 50. I want to add line break between two line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display it as HTML and use \n.

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(someText + "\n" + someOtherText));
```

Obviously there are smarter ways.  Just showing you the Html.fromHtml() method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm very new to Android development so forgive my innocence.Can you please clear me where to put this code and will it show full definitions.txt file as html??